# Upgrade from non-server to server?

Tags: macos, server.app

Is it possible to upgrade from a non-server (desktop) edition of OS X to the server edition? I currently have a Mac Mini running standard ML but I'd like to upgrade it to the Server version as I use it for a home fileserver and the connections frequently get maxed out. Preferably I'd like to go straight from ML -> Mavericks Server, but I don't even know if the desktop-to-server path is possible on any edition without a fresh install (I hope it is).

Comment: The "server" component of OS X is an application installed on an existing system. In 99% of cases consumers don't need OS X server, so look into exactly what your needs are and check out if OS X server has anything that meets those needs. Chances are, it won't, it's mainly focused on corporate infrastructure like wikis, contact/calendar/mail syncing, etc.

Comment: Which connection do max out? Maybe it would be easier to solve this than installing OS X Server, just ask a new question detailing the issue you are facing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OS X Server](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/), from OS X Lion onwards, is just another app you buy from the Mac App Store and install. You **do not** need to do a fresh install of the OS. There are generally no special hardware requirements for OS X Server compared to the client edition either.

To move from OS X Mountain Lion client to OS X Mavericks server, you would first have to upgrade to OS X Mavericks client, then buy and install the Server App from the Mac App Store.

The **General Requirements** section on [OS X Server Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/specs/) page currently states:

> - Mac computer running Mountain Lion.
> - 2GB of memory.
> - 10GB of available disk space; some features require additional disk space.
> - Some features require an Apple ID; terms apply.
> - Some features require a compatible Internet service provider; fees may apply.
> - Some features are not available in all countries.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that?! Thank you!!! Here's the app store link for anyone else looking: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id537441259?mt=12